# How can Edge Loops stay aligned when using the Subsurf Modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I manually aligned each vertext of both marked edge loops in the first image shown (additional edge loops on mudguard and the doors). When a subsurf modifier is added the gap becomes too large as shown in the second image, is there a better technique than realign vertex by vertex after adding the modifier?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the [edge *Crease* weight](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Subsurf#Weighted_Creases) (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or *<kbd>Properties shelf</kbd> <kbd>Transform panel</kbd> <kbd>Mean Crease</kbd>*):

> Weighted edge creases for subdivision surfaces allows you to change the way Subsurf subdivides the geometry to give the edges a smooth or sharp appearance.
>
> The crease weight of selected edges can be changed using Transform Properties (<kbd>N</kbd>) and change the Median Transform slider. A higher value makes the edge “stronger” and more resistant to subsurf. Another way to remember it is that the weight refers to the edge’s sharpness. Edges with a higher weight will be deformed less by subsurf. Recall that the subsurfed shape is a product of all intersecting edges, so to make the edges of an area sharper, you have to increase the weight of all the surrounding edges.

Comment: As usual, your use of `<kbd>` puzzles me..

Comment: Yep, I still think [correct markup](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-kbd-element) is more important than styling conventions. ;)

Comment: @Aldrik: When you say weighted edge creases, are you refering to the "mean crease" option in the transform properties?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to put more parallel edgeloops there. Edges that are close together have more power over the subsurf modifier and create sharper turns. If your topology is clean, the loopcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> works nicely.

You can also select edgeloops with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> and sharpen them with an edge crease <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> (<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd>). I mostly use that with numerical input.